# C++. Updating and copying a series of values each frame. Which class type should I use?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am generating a collection of values each frame and I would like to add those values to a larger collection of values at a specific index.

This is a typical example of a collection I am generating

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> corners;
corners.reserve(8);
//glm::vec3 corners[8];
//std::list<glm::vec3> corners;

corners[i++] = position - hX + hY + hZ;
corners[i++] = position + hX + hY + hZ;
corners[i++] = position + hX - hY + hZ;
corners[i++] = position - hX - hY + hZ;
corners[i++] = position - hX + hY - hZ;
corners[i++] = position + hX + hY - hZ;
corners[i++] = position + hX - hY - hZ;
corners[i++] = position - hX - hY - hZ;
```

I then have a larger collection of glm::vec3 values that I would like to copy the values above to at a particular index.

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
vertices.assign(maxVertices, 0);
```

The C# equivalent would be

```
corners.CopyTo(vertices, index);
```

What class type can I use to efficiently generate and copy the smaller collection across to the larger one without too much overhead of generating it each frame?

I could get away with assigning each newly generated smaller collection to the end of the larger collection so the index value could be ignored.

Comment: Is there not a std::vector.insert() doing just that?

Comment: why not use the array? and just store `corners` somewhere instead of creating it each time;

Comment: I am having problems with std::vector.insert() as I don't wish the array to be dynamically resized.  Initializing it using `vertices.assign(maxVertices, glm::vec3());` causes problems when using insert also.  I'm getting _vector subscript out of range_ errors.

Comment: Do you want to insert the elements from `corners` at position `index` in `vertices`, or you want to copy the values (thus, overwriting some values in `vertices`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you should `corners.resize(8)`, not `corners.reserve(8)`.
Besides, if i understand you correctly, it seems you have always 8 corners?
Use array then:

```
typedef std::array<glm::vec3, 8> Corners; 
// or in pre-c++0B code use boost::array same way
// or if neither is available then just raw glm::vec3[8] can do.
```

Then filling can be done with initialization:

```
// somehow we have position, hX, hY and hZ
Corners corners =
{
    position - hX + hY + hZ,
    position + hX + hY + hZ,
    position + hX - hY + hZ,
    position - hX - hY + hZ,
    position - hX + hY - hZ,
    position + hX + hY - hZ,
    position + hX - hY - hZ,
    position - hX - hY - hZ
};
```

Copying can be done with standard copy:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
// somehow it gets filled

// somewhere comes index

std::copy( corners.begin(), corners.end(), vertices.begin() + index );
// with raw glm::vec3[8] std::copy( corners, corners + 8, vertices.begin() + index );
```

If you need to insert instead of copy then use vertices.insert()

Comment: This is excellent, thank you.  I guess there will not be much of an over head changing the elements of Corners each frame?

Comment: std::vector has some overhead because of its dynamic size. std::array and boost::array perform as good as raw arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). If you want to insert the values in `corners` right before position `index` in vector `vertices` you would do:

```
vertices.insert(vertices.begin() + index, corners.begin(), corners.end());
```

However, that operation would need to make room for the new values. That would shift all the elements from `index` to the end of the vector (and perhaps a vector resizing would be necessary too).

In order to avoid that, you could use a [`list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead.